# How to remove the domain from the start of category in navigation menu

Tags: php, seo, navigation

I have found that the navigation is giving us too many internal links which is not good for seo. To stop this i want the navigation menu to exclude the domain at the beginning of the url eg from: http://example.com/category/subcategory.html to /category/subcategory.html.

I have found this line:
        `$html[] = 'getCategoryUrl($category).'">';`
which i have found to change the urls. I want to make it not show the url at the beginning of the link. What do i need to change to do this, i cannot see what I need to remove or change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the code for getting a category url is in:

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Url
```

You will need to rewrite this class and then implement your own `getCategoryUrl()` method to return the url structure you require.

Alternatively you could create your own category url model and set the following site configuration node `'global/catalog/category/url/model'` to your model.

Comment: Si's answer is indeed correct, however, it won't make any difference at all for SEO purposes. It will still be an internal link.  I'm assuming your menu is listing A LOT if it's becoming a concern.

Comment: @DouglasRadburn We currently have over 500 categories which are appearing and many tools have told us this is too much

Comment: Yes, it is indeed too much, HOWEVER, removing the domain from the link won't make any difference whatsoever. It's still an internal link.